# python split lines remove ;

Tags: python, list

I have this tsv file and i want to remove the ; from the list but it keeps giving me an error message 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split''

```
  import csv

  h = []
  with open('paths_finished.tsv', 'rb') as csvfile:
  ar = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel-tab')

  for row in ar:

      h.append(row[3:4].split(';'))

  print h
```

output:

```
   ['14th_century;15th_century;16th_century]
```

How do i split the ';' in this output?

Comment: Someone else just posted very nearly the same question with very nearly the same code (and the same bug): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909851/keep-getting-error-list-object-has-no-attribute-split Is that your project partner or something?

Comment: Also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22884390/convert-tsv-file-so-i-can-use-it-for-nodes-and-edges-in-python#comment34943854_22884390

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row` is a list, so the slice `row[3:4]` is also a list.

You should just use `row[3]` to get the (string) item from the list

```
for row in ar:
      h.append(row[3].split(';'))
```

You may also use a list comprehension

```
import csv

with open('paths_finished.tsv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    ar = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel-tab')
    h = [row[3].split(';') for row in ar if len(row) > 3]

print h
```

Comment: It says indexError list out of range

Comment: @user3322871, do you have an empty line? You can add a condition `if len(row) > 3` to prevent that

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
>>> my_output = ['14th_century;15th_century;16th_century']   #this is your current output

>>> print my_output[0].split(';')
['14th_century', '15th_century', '16th_century']
```

This takes the first element of your output above and then prints the list based on the string split on `';'`

Comment: Is it me or questions related to this one string list keep popping up pretty often?

Comment: @HerrActress, Huh, yeah! I think we met a few questions ago. Well, nice to see you again!

Answer (score 0):

try this ,

```
>>> ''.join(a)
'14th_century;15th_century;16th_century'
>>> a=''.join(a)
>>> a
'14th_century;15th_century;16th_century'
>>> a.split(';')
['14th_century', '15th_century', '16th_century']
```